# Find Windows 7 thumbnail file name?

Tags: thumbs.db

What are the methods to find the original filename for a thumbnail contained within thumbs.db cache in windows 7? All I see is the file hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs Viewer allows you to extract thumbnail images from the Thumbs.db, ehthumbs.db, ehthumbs_vista.db, Image.db, Video.db, TVThumb.db, and musicThumbs.db database files found on various Windows operating systems.
[here the link for the program](https://thumbsviewer.github.io/)